# Are there Tilt & Turn Replacement Windows?

Tags: windows

[image]

I need to replace the 30 year old cheap vinyl windows in my 1890s home. I’d like to consider using German style Tilt and Turn windows. Most information I see online about these windows are for new construction. I have a couple of questions.

1. Are Tilt and Turn available/advisable as replacement windows?
2. Is there any way to reduce how much space is taken up by the frame (highlighted in red) when installing? The trim will be completely removed and I will have the original window framing exposed.
3. Is there any reason TNT would be a bad idea in this context? The house is structural brick, 2 wythe thick.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Just had TNT windows with frames fitted to my 35 year old property.

They had them made to various sizes from about 2ft square singles to 5 by 7 ft for the double opening ones.

The tilt allows the top to be open about 6".